# Setting embedded Jetty war from classpath

Tags: java, jetty, war, winrun4j

How I can set a war in an embedded jetty in a way that it can load from a classpath. Following is my current code snippet

webAppContext.setWar("hello.war");

Context :-
I want to secure my code other than obfuscation.so, I used Jetty to create a runnable jar and subsequently i used winrun4j to create an exe wrapper. The exe works fine when war file is found at same level but not otherwise even though i've embedded the war in winrun4j exe.

Problem:-
Is there any way that i can set the war in a way that it can pick it up from classpath rather than some pre-defined path.

Hope i communicated the problem statement in a lucid way.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I came around the same and I always extract the war to a temporary location and then use the absolute path;

```
webAppContext.setWar("/path/to/temp/tmp262622522.war");
```

In any case Jetty will extract the war to a temporary location too, when starting the web app.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. See i have no problems with extraction of wars. i've put setExtractWar(false), so, it never gets extracted in temp folder as expected.But I want to protect my war from reverse engineering and hence i embedded it in winrun4j exe but jetty expects the war at same level as that of exe.I just wanna know if there exist any way that jetty loads my war from classpath (winrun4j in this case) instead of pre-defined path because it kills the very purpose of hiding war.